# How to make multiple instances of the same Angular 2 component work properly in the same container

Tags: html, angular, dom, components

I have component `<editor [id]="id">` template like

```
<input id="name" />
<label for="name"></label>
```

and using it with CSS framework like MaterializeCSS which binds labels to inputs using unique HTML DOM id attribute.

Now, If I do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let someThing of listOfSomeThings">
    <editor [id]="someThing.id"></editor>
</div>
```

angular generates many components with the same id, so id attribute is not encapsulated at all and components begin to conflict with each other.

I found a solution by doing this:

```
<input [id]="id + 'name'" />
<label [for]="id + 'name'" />
```

But this looks bad and leads to less maintainable code. Is there any neater and finer way to write fully-encapsulated-dom components (maybe some internal Angular 2 function that I just need to enable)? Or am I to write **all** components in this way to ensure that it will never conflict in such situations?

Comment: How is this less maintainable code? If you want to use the same component on the page more than once, this is a good option to get unique identifiers. Does this: `="id + 'name'`, really work? Looks like you are missing a double quote.

Comment: Yes, it does work. And I missed the double quote. It leads to more cluttered and therefore less maintainable code because now I think that I should use such IDs in each component that I create, even those that I do not use in such a way, because someone could use it in this way. Also, if the component doesn't have unique identifier I have to generate it (like some kind of guid) because someone can put multiple instances at the same page.

Comment: I don't see how this could happen unless you have duplicate ids in your ListOfSomethings. Can you reproduce your problem in this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/62WNlCTtK5WIWVswLYyq?p=preview

Comment: Currently it's like this https://plnkr.co/edit/dNIEIWoZu55KyNQfXiLa?p=preview . Now if I use reactive forms module and try to make `radio` input type - second note and third note's radiobuttons don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use UUID generator for ids or just big random number.

Comment: The question is: should I generate this UUID for **each** component that I create? I've not yet seen any components created in this way, and this is really disturbing me that I can install any third-party component and can't use multiple instances at the same page.

Comment: It would be perfect if Angular 2 had some feature to enable random [id] prefix generation for each component instance. Maybe I should write this to issues at github?

Comment: if you use `id` attribute then you must provide unique value, it has nothing to do with angular.